# How to add dynamic image into canvas and make it rotate, resize, tooltip over the image

Tags: jquery, kineticjs

we are creating a drawing tool, using kinetic js with canvas,

we have to exist code like we are adding image dynamically like a clone and make it rotate, but unable to resize and tooltip over that image.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: still looking for a solution?